# Slow Performance on Ionic4/ Angular7 (Modal, ion-button)

Tags: performance, ionic4, capacitor

I am using Ionic 4/ Angular7 with angular/material to build my app. However I am facing a slow performance issue on my real device (Samgsung C5).

My Page setting is a Home.page contain a headerCompontent, and using a button(modalCtrl) to call the Filter.page from the headerCompontent.

1. **Ion-button**

I have using this Component for building a Filter button with a Icon like this

```
<ion-buttons slot="end" (tap)="show()">
    <ion-button fill="clear">
        <i class="fa fa-cog " aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </ion-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

When the button is clicked, there will be a ripple effect shown and the ripple effect is kind of slow and lag. I have tried to use `(click)` but it is the same.

**2. ion-Modal**

I have a filter page and i try to use modalCtrl to call it out, like below

```
let modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
  component: FilterPage,
  cssClass: "filter animated zoomIn fastest",
  backdropDismiss: true,
  showBackdrop: true,
  animated: false
})
await modal.present();
```

The modal filter is not a full screen modal but a box modal and using Animation.css ZoomIn effect, it is very smooth in the local browser but when i try it on real device, the ZoomIn effect is very slow at the first time being call, it just like using 2-3 frame to finish the whole animation. However, it is much smoother after the first call but still it is not the same as browser.

I have used --prod flag and Capacitor to build the apk. Any suggestion to improve it? like preloading the FilterModal page?

Here is my `ionic info`

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.2.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1

Capacitor:

   capacitor (Capacitor CLI) : 1.0.0-beta.19
   @capacitor/core           : 1.0.0-beta.19

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
   Cordova Platforms     : none
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (5 plugins total)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/gary/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   NodeJS            : v8.11.4 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried to build and run on IPhone, there is no problem, the animation is fast and smooth. 
However, I tried to using another Android phone to test the same things, it still got the slow animation at the first call and got smoother after that.

Both Android phone are on Android 8 and using Chrome WebView.

Comment: When you say "in the local browser", do you mean on your dev desktop / laptop? What is the result when you try in device browser? (Access your dev machine localhost from your device browser) What is the result when you try online demos of Ionic and of your animations.css from your device browser?

Comment: @ghybs Hi, "local browser" mean run "ionic serve" in my dev laptop and the result is very smooth and fast. And i have try to use my phone browser (chrome) to access to my dev laptop, the result is the same as the --prod APK which is very slow at the first time to be called and got little smoother after the first call. So that is my phone issue or what? Thx.

Comment: There's an open issue on Ionics GitHub page - a ripples animation being slow/jumpy on first click. This might be similar https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17699.